# bootstrap button not working inside jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't click on my button and hover doesn't do anything on it. It's inside a jumbotron which I customized a little as you can see in my dump from the firefox console.

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-main">
  <h1 class="hidden-phone" style="font-weight: normal;"  id="index-title">heading</h1>
                                <br />
                <h2 class="subheading" id="index-subtitle">hello</h2>
                <br /> <br />

                <a
                    class="btn btn-large btn-success"  href="http://mylink"  id="index-try-mojo">click</a>
</div>
```

Here's what's displayed in the firefox console :

```
element {
}
#jumbotron-main {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250) !important;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229);
}
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 136, 204);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0px -3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0px 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229);
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 48px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
}
.jumbotron {
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 2.14286;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
body {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
body {
    line-height: 1.4;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
html, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Any idea folks ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to add the container. If you leave the container out the buttons are outside the jumbotron div. Here's how it works for me (without any customisations):

```
  %div.jumbotron
    %div.container
      %div.page-header
        %h1 Employee Login
      %div.col-sm-12
        %div.input-group.input-group-lg
          = f.email_field :email, required: true, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Email"
      %div.col-sm-12
        %div.input-group.input-group-lg
          = f.password_field :password, required: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Your Password"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the `z-index` of your button ?

Edit: I copy pasted your code to the project I'm developing and it's working !

Comment: Yep I just tried to put z-index:10000; but it still doesn't work. It doesn't surprise me that it works for you, I think the problem comes from the custom css that was added on top of the standard bootstrap, but I really don't know what's the origin

Comment: fixed, it was a jumbotron:after { position: absolute } that was in a custom css I picked somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **react-bootstrap**, modifying z-indexes with custom classes results in strange behaviors with different relative values of z-indices for background image and overlay content.

However, on the [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/), I found out you can wrap your content in a `div` with `class="lead"` which adjusts the z-index and other styles appropriately for the overlay content. *You don't have to adjust z-indices at all!*

```
<div className="jumbotron jumbotron-container">
  
  <img src={imgSrc} />

  <div className="lead"> // this class adjusts z-indices
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <Button>Click here</Button> // clickable, hover styles also work
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;

  > .img { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

}
```